# data indirect addressing and adding 16bit numbers AVR assembly

Tags: assembly, avr, addressing

I have a question that begins with this:

```
.dseg

.org 0x200

value1: .byte 2

value2: .byte 2

res: .byte 2
```

Im supposed to compute the sum of res = value1 + value2

```
0x200 value1: 0xCD
0x201         oxAB
0x202 value2: 0x34
0x203         0x12
0x204 res:
0x205
```

and we assume

```
ldi XH,high(value1)
ldi XL,low(value1)
ldi YH,high(value2)
ldi YL,low(value2)
ldi ZH,high(res)
ldi ZL,low(res)
```

Im not sure if this is correct so im trying to get a better understanding of X Y Z and high/low byte. Heres what I did

```
add XL, YL
adc XH, YH
st zh, xh
st zl, xl
```

If this is incorrect how do i get the the high and low bytes into res?

Comment: Please tag the question with the processor type (AVR?).

Comment: @rkhb ok i have now tagged, yes avr atmega2560

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks a lot like a homework, I am not providing the full
solution as code. But this should give you enough hints to fix the code
yourself.

```
.dseg
.org    0x200
value1: .byte 2
value2: .byte 2
res:    .byte 2
```

Here, you are defining `value1`, `value2` and `res` as *symbols*. These
symbols represent the RAM *addresses* you have just assigned for holding
the variables. When you build your program, the linker will replace any
usage of those symbols by the addresses they represent. In other words,
"value1", "value2" and "res" mean "0x0200", "0x0202" and "0x0204"
respectively.

```
ldi XH, high(value1)
ldi XL, low(value1)
ldi YH, high(value2)
ldi YL, low(value2)
ldi ZH, high(res)
ldi ZL, low(res)
```

`ldi` (for "load immediate") means "fill this register with the value I
am providing here, in the source code". There is no RAM access involved,
as the value is carried in the instruction itself. Thus, you are filling
the registers X, Y and Z with the values `0x0200`, `0x0202` and
`0x0204`, respectively. So far so good.

```
add XL, YL
```

Here you are adding the contents of XL (0x00) and YL (0x02), and storing
the result (0x02) back into XL.

```
adc XH, YH
```

Here you are doing the same with XH (0x02) and YH (0x02), and adding
also the carry bit (0). The result (0x04) is sored back into XH.

The previous two instructions combined result in adding X (0x0200) and
Y (0x0202) and soring the result (0x0402) back into X. You have added
the *addresses* of the variables, and the result is hardly meaningful.

What you probably want to do is add the *values* of the variables, i.e.
the *contents* of the RAM at those particular addresses. In order to do
so, you first need to *load* these values from RAM into some CPU
registers, then add the values, then store the sum back into RAM.

For loading from RAM, look at the documentation of the `ld` and `lds`
instructions. Both can be used, in a different way, to solve your
problem. One of them, however, is more in line with the way your
instructor has stated the problem.

Comment: This was not for marks. I think I eventually got the answer after playing around by using the ld to load into registers and then st to store after Adding. Thanks for this explanation it gives more insight to the problem.